# PHP code navigation in Dreamweaver CS 5

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I have started to use Dreamweaver CS5 for PHP coding. The PHP syntax highlighting works fine but I don't get code completion and navigation to work.
For instance in other editors if I press the CTRL key while the mouse cursor is over a variable or function then I can jump to its definition with a mouse click.
Another problem is that when I define a class, usually a hint with a list of methods should appear after inserting "myinstance->" which is not the case in Dreamweaver.
Does Dreamweaver support this? If yes, how can I enable this functionality? Does this also work if the class definition is in a separated file which is referenced with "include"?

Regards,

Comment: DW isn't the best tool out there for php development...What "other editors" you refer to? For PHP you might well switch to other better php-oriented editors

Comment: I have been using NuSphere PhpEd 6 which is very good but has some flaws (slow SFTP upload when using smart upload, horrible search/replace function, I don't like the editor's window management, and sometimes saving of files with the shortcut key stops working and editor has to be restarted). Because I did not want to spend too much money for another product, I tried Dreamweaver which I already use for design and I thought it was ok (e.g. it lacks all the "flaws" I mentioned) except of the code navigation problems I described in the first post.

Comment: You may want to try some free IDEs like Netbeans. Personally, I use CodeLobster, a bit unknown but I like it very much (free, with optional paid plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using aptana studio based on eclipse but slightly faster than eclipse. It has very nice features such as suggestions, auto-complete, code-formatting, highlighting, showing syntax errors on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a css file can help. 
Open a php file -> right click on the page -> CSS Styles -> Attach Style Sheets..
Select your css file. The Code Navigator will be activated

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is not a good PHP IDE, other than syntax highlighting it offers little in the way of tools to help a programmer.

I'd recommend NetBeans as a good free IDE for PHP development.  Eclipse is also free, but I understand that the latest version doesn't really have a working PHP module so you'll have to use the previous to current version.

Comment: It's optimized for 5.1+ with a separate editing mode for 5.3+.